# get latitude and longitude from city name/address/Zipcode and generate XML output

Tags: javascript, html, xml, latitude-longitude

i am try to develop one application. 
with input city name and get the `city, country, country-code, region, latitude and longitude` in XML format...

i am totaly new in latitude and longitude....
i want some thing like this output:-

if input in text-box any city name:- like a:- `Rajkot`
then return:- `city name, country, country_code, region, latitude, longitude`.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are looking for a [google maps Geocoding](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/#XML)

Comment: i thinks its use full for create-xml file... but i am totaly new in them can help me how to start getting city, country, country-code, region, latitude and longitude using city name...